# Shorted a wire and now no outlets work

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I turned off the wrong circuit breaker by mistake and when I cut a wire thinking it was dead there was a large spark.  I went to the circuit breaker box and the circuit breaker did not look as though it had been thrown.  I flipped it anyway and then noticed I was no longer getting power to my kitchen outlets.  I am getting power all the way to my attic 1300 box but the last run of wire to my kitchen outlets no longer seems to carry juice.  How do I diagnose this problem.  It seems certain that the cause was the short but once I flipped the circuit breaker power should have been restored.

Comment: It sounds to me that you are somewhat lucky to still be here with us. Maybe it is time to call in an expert electrician to trouble shoot and fix the problem here.

Comment: Non-contact voltage testers are very inexpensive and absolutely worth it. You just hold the probe up to the wire and it will light up if it's hot. Especially in cases like you describe where there's not an outlet to test, a non-contact voltage tester can literally be a lifesaver.

Comment: Did you repair the wire that you cut?  If you cut the wire, no amount of breaker flipping will restore power.

Comment: Is it possible that you are perhaps not looking at the correct breaker for your kitchen? Have you checked all the breakers (including any sub-panels) for breakers that are switched off?

Comment: A short could have damaged connectors somewhere along the line, especially the push-in type connectors. Locate the last box that still has power and redo all the connections, using only binding posts and wire nuts for connections. Outlets should be pigtailed, their connectors should not be used to carry power through.

Comment: Did the cut hot wire touch any bare neutral/ground wires or metal casing?  If not, **what you are describing is not actually a short** - the arcing you saw would have been only between the hot wires and the cutters.  In that case, the breakers are working correctly (they shouldn't have tripped), and no receptacles should be damaged.  My guess would be you have a tripped GFCI, as Yurly suggests *(you **did** repair the wire, right?)*

Answer (score 6):

Are any of the receptacles ground-fault circuit interrupters (GFCI)? It sounds like you might have tripped a GFCI with multiple receptacles connected to it. Pushing reset should fix the problem.